# How to display text with multiline from JavaScript to the HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display multi line text, from JavaScript to the HTML using looping. The text position is after display the image. The text result should be like 
Place ..... // newline price ....

```
<div id="display">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../controler/package.js"></script>
</div>


var display = document.getElementById('display');

function  buildImages(images,place,k,price){
 var last=document.createElement("IMG");
    last.src=images;
    last.width=800;
    last.height=600;
    last.style.marginTop=30;
    display.appendChild(last);

    var x = document.createElement("H3");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Place:"+place);
    var z = document.createTextNode(" price:"+price);
    x.appendChild(t);
    x.appendChild(z);
    display.insertBefore(x,display.childNodes[k]);
```

Comment: `createTextNode("Place:"+place+"\n");` and `createTextNode("Price:"+price+"\n")` ?

Comment: `var u = document.createElement('br'); x.appendChild(t); x.appendChild(u);`...?

Comment: if you want to display pre-formatted text in html why not just add the text to a <pre> element

Comment: thx heretic Monkey,, its work...

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is probably to do the same thing you would do in HTML: wrap your text nodes in `<p>` elements.

Wrapping the text in an HTML element will always help you later to customize style or whatever!

Raw text nodes are not that convenient.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One is using br tags

```
var x = document.createElement("H3");
var t = document.createTextNode("Place:"+place);
var br = document.createElement("BR");
var z = document.createTextNode(" price:"+price);
x.appendChild(t);
x.appendChild(br);
x.appendChild(z);
```

Another could be using a `pre` tag

```
var x = document.createElement("H3");
var t = document.createTextNode("Place:"+place + "\n price:" + price);
x.appendChild(t);
```

Or you could could use two spans that have display: block;

```
var x = document.createElement("H3");
var t = document.createElement("SPAN");
t.style.display = "block";
t.innerText = "Place:" +place;
var z = document.createElement("SPAN");
z.style.display = "block";
z.innerText = "Price:" +price;
var z = document.createTextNode(" price:"+price);
x.appendChild(t);
x.appendChild(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can not work like this by design. if you do not use

```
 <pre>
```

or

```
 <code>
```

if you want to use line feeds or if you prefer other tags like

```
 <p>
```

then you has to use  at least

```
  <br>
```

by this you can still format the text as you wish. Will look usually a bit messy. I would use a table.